# I want to give my app to some one but it does not work on his computer Python pyinstaller

Tags: python, tkinter, pyinstaller

I have build a store management system and had compiled it with pyinstaller like "pyinstaler -F admin1.py".

It has given me a build file and a dist file when I run the app on my computer it runs perfectly. I have copyed the dist folder to another computer but it does not run so I need to copy the build file to or is their an other way of copying the file to other systems. I am only using tkinter, os module and datetime modules but I have spited my program in different modulus.

Comment: I recently used freeze to compile my python app and give it to my coworker. This worked great so maybe give freeze a shot.

Comment: can you help me out with freeze syntax

Comment: Well it requires a setup.py files with all the build details you will need to go to the cx_freeze website to get all the instructions. I will say that you might run into an issue getting the build data for tkinter so you will likely need to copy the tcl and tk dll's to the build folder after you compile.

Comment: I like pyinstaller and cx_freeze also, in theory any compiled program should run (within reason) on another person's computer if it works on yours without the build folder/files can you find a stacktrace or log that shows why it doesn't work and perhaps explain a in a bit more detail what happens when you try to run it, for instance does it open briefly then close, or something else? Best of luck!

Comment: improve language

Comment: Better use docker

Comment: Doesnt sound right. Delete the dist and build directories and do a clean build . ie pyinstaller --clean -F admin1.py and your binary should be in dist. I've used it for apps and it works v well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't comment, as I don't have enough reputation, but do you have any error messages from the other computer you're trying to run this batch file on?

According to [this section](https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/operating-mode.html) of the pyinstaller documentation, you will need to send the recipient of your executable the "build" directory. This is because build contains all of the dependencies in your script. To quote the section about importing in one folder (**NOTE:** don't worry, I see the onefile option you set. This is just the section where the docs allude to the build directory you're inquiring about):

> Another advantage of a one-folder bundle is that when you change your code, as long as it imports exactly the same set of dependencies, you could send out only the updated myscript executable. That is typically much smaller than the entire folder. (If you change the script so that it imports more or different dependencies, or if the dependencies are upgraded, you must redistribute the whole bundle.)

I think -F still creates a /build directory (so you can still track dependencies). Iwould share that out, as it would be shared with the one folder option as well. Pyinstaller knows to look for Tkinter (also in doc linked above), so at least you don't have to worry about that part. 
When you use onefile, the /dist directory should be empty, or at least it is when I create executables.

Try out the one folder method and send that folder out to whatever computers you need to. Let me know if this helps.

**TLDR;** Yes, share out the build file. It contains all of your dependencies. The dist file shouldn't contain anything for the "-F" option.

Comment: From what I can tell, the binary is in the dist folder when using a -F.

Comment: i am actually   giving the dist folder to the other users do i need to give the build folder to and if so, so how should be those folder placed in other systems

Comment: how would i create one folder option @a7xcarter

Comment: Run pyinstaller again with the --clean option. eg. 
pyinstaller --clean -F admin1.py
You will find there will be a build and dist subdir. The binary you want is in the dist subdir. You can just distribute the binary by itself.